# Could this be my bitcoin?

Tags: wallet

**strong text**Users

Type:

File folder

C:\Windows.old

Location:

Size:

4.33 GB (4.651,209,081 bytes)

Size on disk:

4.34 GB (4,664,881,152 bytes)

Contains:

8,350 Files, 904 Folders

Created:

14 July 2009, 04:20:08

Attribute

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A Windows.old folder is created when you upgrade from one version of the Microsoft Windows operating system to a later version.

Normally, it isn't anything to do with Bitcoin.

Comment: Normally yes,but I'm looking for the bitcoin I mined back in 2009 could this be something? There lot of files/folders

Comment: Try searching for a `wallet.dat` file